# VBA printing external file not working when in loop

Tags: vba, shell, printing

got this great VBA 1 line command to print an external file without opening it.

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName("F:\testprint.pdf").InvokeVerb ("Print")
```

Works perfectly! Now, I tried to insert in on a loop to print a bunch of files in a certain order and it prints the first one and stops, no error given but the macro seems to get stuck for a while.

My code:

```
Sub PrintFile()

    For r = 1 To 3

        FileToPrint = Sheet7.Cells(1 + r, 5).Value

        If FileToPrint = "" Then
            GoTo MainLoop
        Else
            Debug.Print r; " - "; FileToPrint
            CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(0).ParseName(FileToPrint).InvokeVerb ("Print")
            Debug.Print r; " --- "; FileToPrint
        End If
        MainLoop:
    Next r

End Sub
```

Any suggestions, ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you declare the object once outside the for loop and reuse it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the first print job before starting another print job.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If

Sub PrintFile()
    Dim objShell, WshShell
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")


    For r = 1 To 3

        FileToPrint = Sheet7.Cells(1 + r, 5).Value

        If FileToPrint = "" Then
            GoTo MainLoop
        Else
            Debug.Print r; " - "; FileToPrint
            objShell.Namespace(0).ParseName(FileToPrint).InvokeVerb ("Print")
            Sleep 300
            Debug.Print r; " --- "; FileToPrint
        End If
MainLoop:
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @thomas , that solve my problem of not printing in order by delaying each round of `for`. My problem with the whole macro gettting stuck seems to be due to one of the files is on .xlsm format so I solved it handling in another way.